# LocustIO - how to send DELETE query only once

Tags: python, api, rest, http, locust

I am facing with locustIO problem.

Here is the code:

```
@task
def delete_test(self):
for number in range(0, 10):
    response = self.client.request(method="GET", url="api/number/%s" % number,
                                   headers={'X-Username': 'admin', 'X-Password': 'admin'},
                                   catch_response=True)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        self.client.request(method="DELETE", url="api/number/%s" % number,
                            headers={'X-Username': 'admin', 'X-Password': 'admin'})
```

Here is my problem, as you can see, first of all I am checking if %s(number) exists with GET query.

In pure python without locust if I will receive !200 code, DELETE query will not be executed.

But as you know in locust we are simulating users, so the issue is - how to make DELETE only once?

Because after it's deleted another simulated user also tries to delete it one more time and my test fails again and again.

I cannot find the solution even in official documentation/udemy course.

Comment: Little update from my site:
I have also tried to use `self.interrupt()` - still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just use a flag to say whether a particular number has been deleted?

Like this:

```
class MyUser(HttpUser):
    deleted_numbers = {}

    @task
    ...
        if response.status_code == 200 and number not in MyUser.deleted_numbers:
            MyUser.deleted_numbers[number] = True
            self.client.request(method="DELETE", url="api/number/%s" % number, ...)
```

Note that this will not work in a distributed run.